# Adding image links to a specific page in a JavaScript slidshow

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm busy with a e-commerce website and the client wants 3 slide shows running next to each other displaying specials or promotions running on the site. I got it right to run the 3 slide shows next to each other but don't know how to add image links that should you click on that certain special it will take you to the corresponding page.

Please note I'm still a newbie when it comes to JavaScript but I have knowledge of html and css.

Here is the code I used:

This is the code that goes in the head section.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var Imgs=['/images/specials/1.jpg','/images/specials/2.jpg','/images/specials/3.jpg','/images/specials/4.jpg','/images/specials/5.jpg',];
for (var src,z0=0;z0<Imgs.length;z0++){
src=Imgs[z0];
Imgs[z0]=new Image();
Imgs[z0].src=src;
 }

var Imgs1=['/images/specials/3.jpg','/images/specials/4.jpg','/images/specials/5.jpg','/images/specials/1.jpg','/images/specials/2.jpg',]
for (var src,z0=0;z0<Imgs1.length;z0++){
src=Imgs1[z0];
Imgs1[z0]=new Image();
Imgs1[z0].src=src;
 }

var Imgs2=['/images/specials/5.jpg','/images/specials/1.jpg','/images/specials/4.jpg','/images/specials/2.jpg','/images/specials/3.jpg',];
for (var src,z0=0;z0<Imgs2.length;z0++){
src=Imgs2[z0];
Imgs2[z0]=new Image();
Imgs2[z0].src=src; 
 }

//-->
</script>
</head>
```

Next the part that goes into the body section of my page

```
<body>
<img src="/images/1.jpg" id="slide" width="33%" height="300" />
<img src="/images/3.jpg" id="slide1" width="33%" height="300" />
<img src="/images/5.jpg" id="slide1" width="33%" height="300" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function slideit(o){
this.img=document.getElementById(o.ImageID);
if (this.img){
this.ary=o.ImageArray;
this.ms=o.Duration;
this.cnt=0;
this.to=null;
this.slide();
 }
}

slideit.prototype.slide=function(){
this.img.src=this.ary[this.cnt].src;
this.cnt=++this.cnt%this.ary.length;
var oop=this;
this.to=setTimeout(function(){ oop.slide(); },this.ms);
}

new slideit({
ImageID:'slide'
ImageArray:Imgs,
Duration:4500
});

new slideit({
ImageID:'slide1'
ImageArray:Imgs1,
Duration:5500
});

new slideit({
ImageID:'slide2',
ImageArray:Imgs2,
Duration:6500
});

//-->
</script>
</body>
```

If its that easy could you please advise me as how and where to add image links to the code above.

Kind regards,
Jakesza

**Update**

I got the slide to work again what I have noticed is that the script in the body part needs to stay there asoon as I move it to the head section the slide stops working. Also if I add the var=Href parts to the code the slide shows but doesnt transition. Here is a link the page I have been experimenting on.

http://www.compunamics.co.za/test.html

Thanks for your time,

Jakesza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have fun

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var sliderSetup = [
  {
    "id":"slide0",  
    "hrefs":['http://www.google.co.za','http://www.stackoverflow.com','http://www.test.com','http://www.amazon.com','http://www.bidorbuy.co.za'],
    "images":['/images/test/image1.gif','/images/test/image2.gif','/images/test/image3.gif','/images/test/image4.gif','/images/test/image5.gif'],
    "duration":4500
  },
  {
    "id":"slide1",  
    "hrefs":['http://www.bidorbuy.co.za','http://www.stackoverflow.com','http://www.test.com','http://www.amazon.com','http://www.google.co.za'],
    "images":['/images/test/image5.gif','/images/test/image6.gif','/images/test/image7.gif','/images/test/image8.gif','/images/test/image1.gif'],
    "duration":5000
  },
  {
    "id":"slide2",  
    "hrefs":['http://www.google.co.za','http://www.stackoverflow.com','http://www.test.com','http://www.amazon.com','http://www.bidorbuy.co.za'],
    "images":['/images/test/image7.gif','/images/test/image8.gif','/images/test/image1.gif','/images/test/image2.gif','/images/test/image6.gif'],
    "duration":5500
  }
];

function slideit(o){
  this.img=document.getElementById(o.ImageID);
  if (this.img){
    this.ary=[];
    for (var i=0;i<o.ImageArray.length;i++) {
      this.ary[i]=new Image(); 
      this.ary[i].src=o.ImageArray[i];
    }
    this.ms=o.Duration;
    this.cnt=0;
    this.hrefs=o.HrefArray;
    this.to=null;
    this.slide();
  }
}

slideit.prototype.slide=function() {
  this.img.src=this.ary[this.cnt].src;
  this.cnt=++this.cnt%this.ary.length;
  this.img.parentNode.href = this.hrefs[this.cnt];
  var oop=this;
  this.to=setTimeout(function(){ oop.slide(); },this.ms);
}

window.onload=function() {
  for (var i=0;i<sliderSetup.length;i++) {
    new slideit({
      ImageID:sliderSetup[i].id,
      ImageArray:sliderSetup[i].images,
      HrefArray:sliderSetup[i].hrefs,
      Duration:sliderSetup[i].duration
    });
  }
}


//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.co.za"><img alt="" src="/images/test/image1.gif" id="slide0" height="150" width="150" /></a>
<a href="http://www.bidorbuy.co.za"><img alt="" src="/images/test/image5.gif" id="slide1" height="150" width="150" /></a>
<a href="http://www.test.com"><img alt="" src="/images/test/image3.gif" id="slide2" height="150" width="150" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply will post an update as soon as I get it to work again.

Regards,
Jakesza

Comment: @Jakesza Ah, I see the this.img needs to be executed after image load. Sorry, I do not have time to look at this until perhaps Monday. I think my idea was correct though

Comment: Hi again,
I have been playing around with the code you added to the slide I also think your idea is correct but think there is maybe something we are missing maybe. Once I have added your code the slide stopped changing so I think it might be something we need to add code-wise.

Here is the Example of the slide with the links included: http://www.compunamics.co.za/test2.html

Or if there is totally other method to achieve what I need to do in a easier way it would be appreciated. Just need 3 slide on the same webpage which has linkable images to the corresponding slides webpage. 

Regards,

Comment: @Jake - you have some errors. Please remove the Href0= before the } and split this line with a semicolon and a linebreak `this.title = this.HrefArray[this.cnt]var oop=this;`

Comment: @Jake : Fixed it. Change 
`this.img.parentNode.href = this.HrefArray[this.cnt]
  this.title = this.HrefArray[this.cnt]var oop=this;`

to `this.img.parentNode.href = this.hrefs[this.cnt]; var oop=this;`

Comment: @Jake - see update for a full solution as elegant as I could make it without using jQuery :)

Comment: @mplungjan - Wow!! Thanks for your time and the help its much appreciated. This has been a inspiration for me think I'm going to start studying JavaScript. Thanks again =)

Comment: @Jake You are welcome - Javascript is great fun :) Notice I got it to run on page load too so no script in the body needed